# Car won't start.

Tags: battery, starting, alternator, pontiac, g6

I have a 2009 pontiac g6 gt and my car will not start and I am trying to figure out why. Over the past few years I have replaced both the alternator and battery twice, and they both keep failing at some point. Right now my battery is at 4 volts and there is nothing when I turn the key. I have changed my negative battery wires as well as changed the wire lead to the alternator, that was previously melting. So I figured I have some kind of short, I just don't know where to look, and how I should fix the problem, or even if it is worth fixing.

Comment: at 4 volts your battery is dead beyond all hope. Dont bother trying to jump it or charge it, throw it away. You will need to put a new battery in before you can diagnose whatever else may be wrong.

Comment: @agentp is entirely correct about the battery, but figure out what's wrong before putting a new one in or you'll ruin that one too and waste your money.

Comment: I know I just don't know how to go about figuring out what is wrong. The car has always had electrical issues. When I first got it the car the wiring harness for the headlights would burn completely thru. I changed the headlight harness and the bulbs and I haven't had an issue with that since. But now it seems to be connected with the battery and alternator with the wire to the alternator completely burning as well. I changed all the wires and made sure they all had solid connections, and all the wires are healthy looking.

Comment: right, i meant get battery and immediately figure whats wrong. The melted alternator wire was likely caused by the alternator itself btw. Its not clear from your story the order of events.  another thing be sure to inspect the fuse box (the one under the hood) for correct fuses and anything melted in there.

Comment: I got you. Sorry I was unclear. The thing with the lights happened first. Which led me to believe there is a short or power surge somewhere. After which over the course of two years I have been having the current problem. At first it was just the alternator, where the wire had burnt out. So I replaced that. Then it was both the battery and the alternator that needed to be replaced, and now my battery is completely shot. I don't know I will check the fuses to see how that looks. But one other thing I just remembered, it happened to me twice, while driving the car, it completely shutoff.

Comment: What's the gauge of the alternator wire? You're probably going to have to replace the battery, check for parasitic draw, do a cranking voltage drop test to the engine ground and hook an amp clamp up to measure how many amps the alternator is putting out under load. I'd think that the cause of the alternator cable burning up would be a poor ground either from the engine to alt or engine to frame/battery.